# How to find the least frequently fetched rows from a table in mysql using python?

Tags: python, mysql

In our application we always have to free up some space for new data storage. If there is not enough space then we have to delete some old data to make space for some new data. We might need the deleted data again so we have to fetch it again. We cant just delete the oldest data as it may be needed again. Is there any way I can find the least frequently fetched rows from Mysql using python? 
I also need some way to decide how many rows to delete. I can find out that I have 20 mbs of free space but then how many rows to delete and which ones to delete? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You should look into "LRU" (least recently used) and "LFU" (least frequently used).

Comment: I know this but how do I check this in the database?